# How to getIdtoken on authentication

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I just need to print Idtoken of user's once he is authenticated.
I'm using phone authentication of firebase in flutter.

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
            if (user != null) {
              var idtoken = user.getIdToken().toString();
              print("Firebase uid: "+idtoken);}}
```

how to correct this

Answer (score 17, accepted):

based on https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User.html#getidtoken you need to handle the promise from the `getTokenId()` method call.

your code becomes:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then(user => {
        if (user != null) {
           user.getIdToken().then(token => {
             //handle token
           }
        }
});
```

Comment: you may have an old version of JS  doesnt support node...OR...The closing curly (updated). but come on, you have the IDE, you should be able to resolve a syntax error...

Comment: OK i got it, Thanks allot buddy

Answer (score 5):

The same with async-await

```
final tokenResult = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
final idToken = await tokenResult.getIdToken();
final token = idToken.token;
```